# Cannot add Background color on Kotlin Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, background-color

I want to add a background color on my Floating Action Button but I cannot seem to add it. On older Yotuube videos adding a backgroundColor would make it possible but it seems that it is not possible to do it now. Any help?

````
@Composable
fun HomeView(){
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Scaffold(

        topBar = {AppBarView(title = "WishList",{
            Toast.makeText(context,"Button Clicked:",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        })},
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 20.dp),
                contentColor = Color.White,
                //I want to add a Background color here
                onClick = { //TODO Add Navigation to edit screen}) {
                
            }
        }
    ) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(it)){

        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `containerColor` for it. In the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#FloatingActionButton(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.material3.FloatingActionButtonElevation,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function0)) it says

> the color used for the background of this FAB. Use Color.Transparent to have no color.

If you don't set it, the contentColor is used by default.